# Getting the source ROI coordinates of a cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

in opencv there is no difference between an image and a ROI of an image. a cv::Mat object can be either:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread(fileName);
cv::Mat imgROI(img,cv::Rect(1,2,30,40));
```

My question is how can I extract the original ROI coordinates in the original image, i.e. some function that preforms the following:

```
cv::Rect originalROIcoords  = roiLocationInOriginalImg(imgROI);
cv::Rect originalROIcoords2 = roiLocationInOriginalImg(img );
```

*originalROIcoords* should be (1,2,30,40), while *originalROIcoords2* should be (0,0,w,h), where *w* and *h* are the original image width and height respectively.

Thanks.

Ohad

Comment: To know the coordinates of a submatrix in the original matrix, can't you use the function Mat::locateROI ?

// locates matrix header within a parent matrix
void locateROI( Size& wholeSize, Point& ofs ) const;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know the coordinates of a submatrix in the original matrix, you can use the function `Mat::locateROI`

```
// locates matrix header within a parent matrix
void locateROI( Size& wholeSize, Point& ofs ) const;
```

Answer (score 10):

Be carefull with ROI of ROI because locateROI returns offset related to root image and it's not related to ROI parent

```
cv::Mat img(100,100,CV_8UC1);               // the root image
cv::Mat imgROI(img,cv::Rect(10,10,60,60));  // a ROI in the root image
cv::Mat roiROI(imgROI,cv::Rect(5,5,30,30)); // a ROI into a ROI

Point offset;
Size wholesize;
```

Get the offset of 1st ROI:

```
imgROI.locateROI(wholesize,offset);
cout << "imgRoi Offset: " << offset.x <<","<< offset.y << endl;
```

> imgRoi Offset: 10,10

Get the offset of roi of ROI:

```
roiROI.locateROI(wholesize,offset);
cout << "roiRoi Offset: " << offset.x <<","<< offset.y << endl;
```

> roiRoi Offset: 15,15

same is for `wholesize`

Comment: I'd say this answer is much better than the accepted one. As it provides examples of use as well as some guidelines on what to watch out for. +1